# Internal (memory) representation of TProc and references at all

Tags: delphi, reference

Does anyone here know how Delphi represents a reference to procedure?

for example

```
var
  proc: TProc;
...
proc = procedure begin beep end;
```

What do we got in "proc"?

I know that for "method variable" the memory representation is 4 bytes for the "procedure address" followed by 4 bytes for the "object address", but for "reference to procedure" is somewhat different and I cannot quite figure it out.

The reason I want this is because I have some legacy code that I want to make it work with references.

Does anyone know something about it?

Comment: http://alex.ciobanu.org/?p=27

Comment: In general `reference to procedure` is held in a special compiler generated interface variable. This ensures that it is reference counted so that the captured variables can be tidied away when no references remain.  You don't need to know how it is implemented in order to work with `reference to`.  That's why you have a compiler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Method references are implemented as a COM-style interface with a single method called `Invoke`, which has the same signature as the method reference.

So `TProc` looks like this:

```
type
  TProc = interface(IInterface) // so inherits QI, AddRef, Release
     procedure Invoke;
  end;
```

It's a valid question to ask, as Delphi has interoperability with the C++ product. By using a pre-existing reference-counted type and idiom (COM lifetime rules), interop with C++ at the method reference level is possible.

Anonymous methods generate a hidden class which implements an interface isomorphic to the method reference interface, i.e. exactly the same shape, but not with the same symbolic identity. The hidden class doesn't implement the method reference interface directly because it may need to implement the interface multiple times (a single block may contain multiple anonymous methods all assigned to locations of the same method reference type).

Comment: @Barry: Interesting as always! I had to read the last paragraph several times, but I think I understand.  This may be a silly question, I'm afraid, but: does the bracketed section mean that the one instance of a method reference hidden class is created to implement multiple anonymous methods, where several are all defined in the same normal procedure (or same other scope)? That sounds... complicated :)

Comment: @David anonymous methods may capture local variables; when you have several anonymous methods all capturing the same variable, they need to share state. Delphi's implementation puts all the state (i.e. captured variables) associated with anonymous methods in a block into the same object; every anonymous method gets turned into a method on this object's class, while every captured variable turns into a field.

Comment: @Barry: thanks! I didn't realise the point was to share state, I was thinking keeping lots of separate states in the one object (one set per method, just using one object for... some reason, overhead maybe?) sounded messy. Makes a lot more sense now :)